# Sound playback glitches with Windows 7 on Core i3 when CPU under load

Tags: audio, intel-core-i3

**Processor:** Intel Core i3-2125
**Chipset:** Intel H67 (Cougar Point) [B3]
**Sound Card:** External Creative Soundblaster (don't remeber the model exactly)
**Players:** VLC, in browser Groovershark.com

When the processor gets loaded, e.g. compiling something in Visual studio this interrupts playback for short periods of time.

This also happens on my home PC with the same processor and chipset, but a different vendor of the motherboard and a PCI Creative soundcard.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image: HW Info Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can try raising the priority of the VLC process, or lowering the priority of Visual Studio (although I wouldnt recommend the latter).

Open up the Task Manger, select the Processes tab and find VLC.  Right click and click Set Priority.  Try bumping it up one level at a time.  I would avoid Realtime tho, that might freeze the system.

Comment: Thanks! With realtime + affinity it seems to work with almost no glitches so far.

Comment: Turns out the glitches persist after bumping up the priority :(